# É possível integrar testes com o SELENIUM IDE no Github?

Tags: github, selenium-webdriver

Tenho alguns testes com o SELENIUM IDE e gostaria de integrar ele com um repositório no Github. É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, não.

Já o Selenium Webdriver pode ser integrado à API do GitHub. A diferença entre o Selenium IDE e o Selenium Webdriver é que você terá que programar o código em alguma linguagem. A GitHub possui bibliotecas para a API nas seguintes linguagens:

- [C#](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net);
- [Python](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub);
- [Java](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api);
- [Ruby](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estava quebrando a cabeça só para saber se havia essa possibilidade e você além de respondê-la, me trouxe uma solução. Vlw mesmo!

Comment: @vacobs10 [Veja aqui como usar o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Bons estudos!